# Pass value from Page to User Control

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, user-controls

I have a custom user control called in the Default.aspx page:

```
<myPrefix:myTagName ID="category" runat="server" />
```

The code behind for the custom user control:

```
namespace WebApplication3.inc.controls {
    public partial class myTag : System.Web.UI.UserControl {
        public String id;
        public String name;
        public String value;
        public Hashtable attributes;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (this.id != null)
                this.attributes["id"] = this.id;
            if (this.name != null)
                this.attributes["name"] = this.name;
            if (this.value != null)
                this.attributes["value"] = this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

in the Default.aspx.cs code, I'd like to set the value of this tag:

```
this.articleCategory.value = this.currentArticle.Category.ToString();
```

I get this error at 'value' in this last line:

> 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not
>   contain a definition for 'value' and
>   no extension method 'value' accepting
>   a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.UI.UserControl' could be
>   found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

All of the demos that I've seen seem to indicate that this should work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that the reference to your control instance from your page class is currently of type `System.Web.UI.UserControl`. It needs to be of type `WebApplication3.inc.controls.myTag` to access the `value` member. One way to fix this is to move the declaration of the variable to the codebehind file rather than having Visual Studio autogenerate the variable, but the exact way this is done depends on your project settings and how you included the control in the page.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you are calling it at the wrong time, `Page_Load` is called on the page first and then all child controls on the page. Maybe you just need to change the control to initialize itself on `Init` instead of `Page_Load`

Comment: actually Jonas answer is more likely